# javascript value is not updating after onmousevent

Tags: javascript, html, feedback

I use 1 span tag at the moment.

```
<span onmouseover="numberOne()" onclick="imgNumber(); return false"  onmouseout="noHoverOne()" class="img1 img" id="new-img"> </span>
```

The span has a "deafult" image, when the mouse goes on the span, another image will be shown, when the mouse leaves the span, the default image will be shown again.

now the javascript:

```
function numberOne() {
  var random2 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) + 1);
  var random3 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) + 1);

  do {
    var random = Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) + 1);
  } while (random === numberOne.last);

  numberOne.last = random;
```

Random numbers are made here. So every time you leave the span and go on the span, there will be a different image.

```
if (random == 2) {
  document.getElementById('new-img').style = "background-image: url('http://web-stars.nl/molgeld.jpg');";
} else if ((random==random2)==random3) {
  document.getElementById('new-img').style = "background-image: url('http://web-stars.nl/vrijstelling.jpg');";
} else {
  document.getElementById('new-img').style = "background-image: url('http://web-stars.nl/haspel.jpg');";
}
```

These are the images that will be shown depending on the number

```
  return random;
}

var value = numberOne();

function imgNumber() {
  document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = value;                
}

imgNumber();
```

This is where I am stuck. Before I even have touched the span tag with my mouse, there is already a random number and when I go with the mouse on the span tag, it shows a different image but not a different number. I want to use this number somehow to create a new level for my game. The game is influenced by the chosen image.

So there is a lot going on and it's pretty messy. So please, I would love to hear any kind of constructive feedback.

[EDIT] I will keep the JSfiddle up to date, but there is an error in the preview, it won't display anything. It's still useful  [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5gkw17mt/1)

Comment: You call *numberOne* and *imgNumber* from global code, so yes, there are already values for *numberOne.last* and in the *demo* element (assuming the code is run after the elements exist). And yes, the code is pretty messy for the logic it's implementing.

Comment: Can you maybe help me to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a wrapper function where you can call both `imgNumber` and `numberOne`

```js
function mouseHover() {
  var value = numberOne()
  imgNumber(value)
}

function imgNumber(value) {
  document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = value;              
}
```

```html
<span onmouseover="mouseHover()" onclick="imgNumber(); return false"  onmouseout="noHoverOne()" class="img1 img" id="new-img"> </span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a bit illogical. It seems you want to randomly assign an image to an element background and get a different element each time. So put the image URLs in an array and randomly grab one, ensuring it's different to the last. This means you can add or reduce the images you want to display just by modifying the images array.

Also put all your data in an object rather than using globals, it's just neater. And give your functions names that tell you what they do.

E.g.

```js
var imageData = {
  pix: ['http://web-stars.nl/molgeld.jpg',
    'http://web-stars.nl/vrijstelling.jpg',
    'http://web-stars.nl/haspel.jpg'
  ],
  random: null
}

function changeImage(el) {
  // limit do loop just in case data is bad
  // Infinite loops are bad...
  var len = imageData.pix.length;
  var i = len;

  do {
    var random = Math.random() * len | 0;
  } while (i-- && imageData.random == random)

  imageData.random = random;
  el.style.backgroundImage = imageData.pix[random];
  console.log(random, imageData.pix[random]);
}

function updateImageRef() {
  document.getElementById('imageRef').textContent = imageData.random;
}
```

```html
<div id="imageDiv" onmouseover="changeImage(this)" onclick="updateImageRef()">Image div</div>
<div id="imageRef"><div>
```

Comment: I don't want to get a different element each time, I want a different image each mouseover. But there shouldn't be 2 of the same images in a row. 
I will try your code! I will let you know

Comment: and what I also don't understand is how I can affect the game with the image number